# Loading chararray from embedded JSON using Pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, hue

I am trying to import JSON data into Pig using the code:

```
Data = LOAD '/log/2015/06/07-TAG-AD.json.bz2'
USING JsonLoader('user: (ui:long, date:datetime, ua:chararray, ip:chararray, id:long, cntry:chararray, cty:chararray, x:float, y:float, gender:int, age:int), inv: (w:int, h:int, url:chararray, do:chararray, pos:int, adx:int, net: chararray, adv:int, dea:int), resp: (adv:long, oi:long, c:long, cr:long, p:double, b:double)'); 
DUMP Data;
```

However I keep on getting the error:

> ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1433718762047_0074_m_000000_3 Info:Error: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('M' (code 77)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

I imagine that it is comming from the field user.ua field since this is what the JSONs look like:

```
({  "_id" : ObjectId("5573fcdfba0947360b8f0144"),  "user" : {  "ui" : NumberLong("3559044716429019182"),  "date" : ISODate("2015-06-07T08:12:15.047Z"),  "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36",  "ip" : null,  "id" : null,  "cntry" : "FR",  "cty" : "Toulouse",  "x" : null,  "y" : null,  "gender" : null,  "age" : null },  "inv" : {  "w" : 300,  "h" : 250,  "url" : "http://www.ladepeche.fr/",  "do" : "ladepeche.fr",  "pos" : null,  "adx" : 1,  "net" : null,  "adv" : 1,  "dea" : null },  "resp" : {  "adv" : NumberLong(449290),  "oi" : NumberLong(1862027),  "c" : NumberLong(7772668),  "cr" : NumberLong(28041668),  "p" : 2.518448,  "b" : 2.55584 } })
```

Shouldn't the chararray data type be able to recognise the letter 'M'?

Comment: Why is ua declared as ua:bytearray and not as ua:chararray in the loader configuration ?

Comment: sorry, I copied the wrong script. That was something else I tried that also didn't work.

Comment: You may provide a JSON example (and check its validity first)